# Quick count of k moments in python

Tags: python

I need to count 1 ... k moments for an array of values. How to do it optimally?
Perhaps there is a library that allows you to do this quickly?

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
moments = []
for i in range(1, k + 1):
   mid = 0
   for j in array:
      mid += j
   mid /= len(array)

   sum = 0
   for j in array:
     sum += (j - mid)**i
   sum /= len(array)
   moments.append(sum)
```

[image: formula]

Comment: Add full code of your equation

Comment: [`scipy.stats.moment`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.moment.html)?

Comment: Сan this be done without looping over k?

Comment: I see your code computes the `sum()` of `array` manually on every iteration. That's surely something to move outside of it. Apart from that, your question is a bit unclear, what exactly do you want to achieve? If you want a code review, consider posting this to codereview.stackexchange.com instead, read their site guidelines first though! As a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: i think there is an optimization to be made for each iteration.  `j-mid` will be the same each time, and you just need to do 1 additional multiplication to go from (j - mid) ^ 3 to (j - mid) ^ 4, so this could definitely be optimized a lot

Answer (score 0):

`SciPy` library. More specific: `scipy.stats.moment`. This function calculates the nth moment about the mean for a sample.

```py
from scipy.stats import moment
import numpy as np

array = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
k = 4
moments = [moment(array, moment=i) for i in range(1, k + 1)]
print(moments)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pre-calculate *c*, *n* and the deltas

Use a list comprehension as follows:

```
_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

n = len(_list)
c = sum(_list) / n
k = 4
t = [1/n] * n
d = [v-c for v in _list]
moments = [sum(t := [x * y for x, y in zip(t, d)]) for _ in range(k)]
print(moments)
```

**Output:**

```
[0.0, 2.9166666666666665, 0.0, 14.729166666666666]
```

...which is exactly the same output that you'd get from *scipy* should you decide to import and utilise that module